# How return previous stage after using git reset --hard?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have 2 local branches: `master` and `another_branch`.

This branches have few commits on server.

My tracked branch: `another_branch`.

I use `git reset --hard` and current branch loses all current local commits. But on server all is no different.

How do I can return previous stage before using hard reset?

Comment: Can you clarify _return previous stage_?

Comment: @user2062950 Get all my commits from server to current branch (any_branch)

Comment: You can do a `git pull` or a `git fetch`. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch) explains the difference between the two.

Comment: @user2062950 Ok, thanks! But I use SmartGit/Hg and SSH key. SmartGit does not permit to use the console. How I can resolve this trouble?

Comment: There should be a Pull or Fetch option somewhere in the GUI. Whether or not you're using SSH keys is irrelevant in this case. Try looking at their [documentation](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can [find the `git.exe` used by SmartGit in the logs](http://smartgit.3668570.n2.nabble.com/GIT-commands-sent-by-SmartGit-td4113010.html).
Once you have [fetch through smartGit Gui](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/documentation?page=commands) (Pull, with the option "Fetch only" selected), you can in a console locally do a:

```
git checkout another_branch
git reset --hard origin/another_branch
```

It will reset your local branch to the one referenced by the [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) '`origin`', but it will also remove any local modification that you might have (a `git stash` before the reset is prudent).

Comment: but any_branch has been deleted by hard reset. Maybe I use `git checkout master` before using hard reset.

Comment: @toodef if `another_branch` doesn't exist (`git branch` doesn't show it), then create it: `git checkout -b another_branch --track origin/another_branch`.